# These two spaces are not homeomorphic...right?

Tags: general-topology

why is $\Bbb R\times[0,1]\not \cong \Bbb R^2$? we can't use the popular argument of deleting a point and finding that one has more path components than the other here.

So my idea is to delete a strip $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ from $\Bbb R\times[0,1]$.

But is $\Bbb R^2-f(\{0\}\times[0,1])$ always path-conneted when $f:\Bbb R\times[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ is a homeo?

Comment: If you know some algebraic topology, then you could delete the point $(0,0)$ from $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$; the result is contractible, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus a point retracts to a circle and is not contractible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus a point is **not** homeomorphic to a circle (think topological dimension, e.g.).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I meant retractible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That spaces have different one-point (Alexandroff) [compactifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28mathematics%29), hence they cannot be homeomorphic.

The one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the sphere $S^2$, while the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ is a closed disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a pair of its boundary points identified. In $S^2$, two open neighbourhoods of two different points are always isomorphic, and by removing any point in a neighbourhood it stays connected. In the last space, there is a point $u$ with an unusual behaviour: by taking an open neighbourhood $U$ of $u$, $U\setminus\{u\}$ is disconnected.

Comment: In the sense of Stone-Čech (for the strip)? Is there an easy way to see this? (Other than intuitively of course!)

Comment: @AlexProvost: in the sense of Alexandroff.

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't that mean that removing a point from the closed cylinder should yield a space homeomorphic to the strip? But the closed cylinder minus a point has nontrivial fundamental group.

Comment: My argument is just an alternative to the other one. If we remove *some* point from $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$, the fundamental group may still be trivial, but that never happens for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It is incorrect to speak of "the" compactifications of these spaces . What is true is that their one-point (Alexandroff) compactifications are not homeomorphic. The one-point comp'n of $R\times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to a closed disc in $R^2$ with a pair of its boundary points identified.

Comment: @user254665: thank you, now fixed.

Comment: I added the words "one-point" in my edit. I like the simple way you show they are not homeomorphic, without needing homotopy theory.+1.

Comment: I just saw another flaw which I leave to you to fix. I think you didn't  say what you meant to say: In $S^2$ every point  $p$ has a nbhd base  $B_p$  such that $b$ \ $\{p\}$ is connected for all $b\in B_p$ .But $u$ has no such nbhd base.

Comment: @user254665: I hope my answer is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The property of simple connectivity will distinguish between $\Bbb{R} \times[0,1]$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$. When we remove one point from $\Bbb{R} \times[0,1]$ then it is simply connected but removing one point from $\Bbb{R}^2$ then it is not simply connected.

Comment: Well not any point, it has to be one on the _edge_.

Comment: it can be any point.

Comment: No it can't: remove $(0,1/2)$ from $\mathbb R \times [0,1]$ and there no way to get an homotopy from a loop based at $(1,1/2)$ going _around the hole_ to the constant loop. You want to choose a point on the edge, say $(0,0)$, which prevent any loop to go around it.

Comment: you are absolutely right..thanx,,

Answer (score 1):

To riff off Jack D'Aurizio's idea to use compactifications (and trying to avoid Algebraic Topology notions...):

The Cech-Stone compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a connected remainder, while that of $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ has two components in its remainder. The proof is similar to that of the Cech-Stone compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

The Freudenthal compactification should have the same properties for its remainder as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are already more elementary answers given, but the Invariance of Domain theorem immediately shows they are not homeomorphic, as your strip is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another variation on the idea of using compactifications to avoid algebraic topology: $\Bbb R\times[0,1]$ has a two-point compactification, but $\Bbb R^2$ does not.

The two-point compactification of $\Bbb R\times[0,1]$ is pretty evident. Suppose that that $\Bbb R^2$ has a compactification $X=\{p,q\}\cup\Bbb R^2$, where $p\ne q$. Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint open nbhds of $p$ and $q$; $K=\Bbb R^2\setminus(U\cup V)$ is a compact subset of the plane. Let $G=U\cap\Bbb R^2$ and $H=V\cap\Bbb R^2$; $G$ and $H$ are open in $\Bbb R^2$ and partition $\Bbb R^2\setminus K$.

$K$ is compact, so let $r_0=\max\{\|x\|:x\in K\}$. For each $r>r_0$ let $C_r$ be the circle of radius $r$ centred at the origin. $C_r$ is connected, so for each $r\ge r_0$ we must have $C_r\subseteq G$ or $C_r\subseteq H$. Let $I_G=\{r>r_0:C_r\subseteq G\}$ and $I_H=\{r>r_0:C_r\subseteq H\}$. Each $C_r$ is compact, so $I_G$ and $I_H$ are open subsets of the connected set $(r_0,\to)$; without loss of generality $I_G=(r_0,\to)$ (and $I_H=\varnothing$). It follows that $H$ is a bounded open set in $\Bbb R^2$ and hence that $W=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R^2}H$ is an open nbhd of $q$ in $X$. But then $V\cap W=\{q\}$ is open in $X$, and $q$ is isolated, which is impossible.

Comment: Every remainder of $\mathbb R ^2$ is connected as it is the intersection of  continua $\text{cl}_{\gamma \mathbb R ^2}\mathbb R ^2 \setminus B(0,n)$ , whereas clearly $\mathbb R \times [0,1]$ has a non-connected remainder.

Comment: @ForeverMozart: That comment essentially makes the connection between my answer and Henno’s. Mine is intended to be as elementary as possible.